Vaadin Flow React Integration - ExecutionFailedException: Npm install has exited with non zero status. Some dependencies are not installed
I am trying out the Vaadin Flow React integration and my goal is to add a simple button from next-ui to a view.

I create the java component. After the applications is built I see in the package.jsonthat the @nextui-org/react dependeny was added.

package de.philipp.views.test;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.Tag;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.dependency.JsModule;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.dependency.NpmPackage;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.react.ReactAdapterComponent;

@NpmPackage(value = "@nextui-org/react", version = "2.4.6")
@JsModule("./react/next-ui-button.tsx")
@Tag("next-ui-button")
public class NextUiButton extends ReactAdapterComponent {

    public NextUiButton() {
        setLabel("Click me");
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return getState("label", String.class);
    }

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        setState("label", label);
    }
}


I also create the corresponding .tsx file:

import {type ReactElement} from 'react';
import {type RgbaColor, RgbaColorPicker} from "react-colorful";
import {ReactAdapterElement, type RenderHooks} from "Frontend/generated/flow/ReactAdapter";

class RgbaColorPickerElement extends ReactAdapterElement {
  protected override render(hooks: RenderHooks): ReactElement | null { 
    const [color, setColor] =
      hooks.useState<RgbaColor>("color"); 

    return <RgbaColorPicker
      color={color}
      onChange={setColor}
    />; 
  }
}

customElements.define(
  "rgba-color-picker",
  RgbaColorPickerElement
); 


Finally I am adding the button to a view:

package de.philipp.views.test;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.H1;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;
import com.vaadin.flow.server.auth.AnonymousAllowed;

import de.philipp.views.MainLayout;

@Route(value = "test", layout = MainLayout.class)
@AnonymousAllowed
public class TestView extends VerticalLayout {

    public TestView() {
        H1 h1 = new H1("Test");
        
        NextUiButton button = new NextUiButton();
        add(h1, button);
    }
}

But I get the following error:
com.vaadin.flow.server.ExecutionFailedException: Npm install has exited with non zero status. Some dependencies are not installed. Check npm command output
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.TaskRunNpmInstall.runNpmInstall(TaskRunNpmInstall.java:334) ~[flow-server-24.4.2.jar:24.4.2]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.TaskRunNpmInstall.execute(TaskRunNpmInstall.java:115) ~[flow-server-24.4.2.jar:24.4.2]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.NodeTasks.execute(NodeTasks.java:348) ~[flow-server-24.4.2.jar:24.4.2]
    at com.vaadin.base.devserver.startup.DevModeInitializer.runNodeTasks(DevModeInitializer.java:356) ~[vaadin-dev-server-24.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.base.devserver.startup.DevModeInitializer.lambda$initDevModeHandler$0(DevModeInitializer.java:297) ~[vaadin-dev-server-24.4.2.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1804) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1796) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:387) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1312) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1843) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1808) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:188) ~[na:na]

and the npm debug log shows:
606 verbose stack Error: Unable to resolve reference $react-dom
606 verbose stack     at get spec [as spec] (/home/philipp/Documents/java-projects/openbsp2/node/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/edge.js:202:15)
606 verbose stack     at #nodeFromEdge (/home/philipp/Documents/java-projects/openbsp2/node/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:1054:46)
606 verbose stack     at #loadPeerSet (/home/philipp/Documents/java-projects/openbsp2/node/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:1320:35)
606 verbose stack     at async #buildDepStep (/home/philipp/Documents/java-projects/openbsp2/node/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:923:11)
606 verbose stack     at async Arborist.buildIdealTree (/home/philipp/Documents/java-projects/openbsp2/node/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:203:7)
606 verbose stack     at async Promise.all (index 1)
606 verbose stack     at async Arborist.reify (/home/philipp/Documents/java-projects/openbsp2/node/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:131:5)
606 verbose stack     at async Install.exec (/home/philipp/Documents/java-projects/openbsp2/node/node_modules/npm/lib/commands/install.js:150:5)
606 verbose stack     at async module.exports (/home/philipp/Documents/java-projects/openbsp2/node/node_modules/npm/lib/cli/entry.js:74:5)
607 verbose cwd /home/philipp/Documents/java-projects/openbsp2
608 verbose Linux 6.8.0-39-generic
609 verbose node v20.14.0
610 verbose npm  v10.7.0
611 error Unable to resolve reference $react-dom
612 verbose exit 1
613 verbose code 1
614 silly unfinished npm timer reify 1722091492412
615 silly unfinished npm timer reify:loadTrees 1722091492417
616 silly unfinished npm timer idealTree:buildDeps 1722091493590
617 silly unfinished npm timer idealTree:node_modules/@nextui-org/use-aria-accordion 1722091505384
618 error A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/philipp/.npm/_logs/2024-07-27T14_44_51_799Z-debug-0.log

My pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <!-- Project from
    https://start.vaadin.com/project/f3a5be16-7eee-4ba4-a216-38d2fcb9c1f2 -->
    <groupId>de.philipp</groupId>
    <artifactId>open-bsp</artifactId>
    <name>open-bsp</name>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>24.4.4</vaadin.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.8</version>
    </parent>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Vaadin Directory</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <!-- Replace artifactId with vaadin-core to use only free components -->
            <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.parttio</groupId>
            <artifactId>line-awesome</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-testbench-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mindrot</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbcrypt</artifactId>
            <version>0.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>spring-boot:run</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <nodeAutoUpdate>true</nodeAutoUpdate>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- Production mode is activated using -Pproduction -->
            <id>production</id>
            <dependencies>
                <!-- Exclude development dependencies from production -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>vaadin-core</artifactId>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                            <artifactId>vaadin-dev</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>it</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>start-spring-boot</id>
                                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>start</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>stop-spring-boot</id>
                                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>stop</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

                    <!-- Runs the integration tests (*IT) after the server is
                    started -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
                            <enableAssertions>true</enableAssertions>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

    </profiles>
</project>

I used npm list to verfiy that react-dom next ui etc. is installed and it is. I also tried a maven clean install. Lastly I deleted the node_modules folder and the package-lock.json and genereated them again.

Can you check if the location you defined in JsModule is correct

@SimonMartinelli Yes the location is correct. I also implemented a React color picker from react-colorful and that worked. My App seems to have a problem with the nextui dependency specify...

From my personal experience, the Error: Unable to resolve reference $react-dom or in general Unable to resolve reference ${some-package-name} is happening due to an open bug in npm/cli and it can happen randomly to any of the packages listed in the "overrides": { ... } object of package.json.
While the bug with npm/cli is not resolved, a temporary solution is to:

Locate the override with the value of ${some-package-name} (in your case $react-dom) and replace the value with the actual latest version of that package, and try npm install again.

It is common to see the same error but with another package e.g. $react-router-dom, $react, or something else (normally it is only a handful of them), so continue replacing them with the actual latest versions, and run npm install to make sure you've replaced all of them.

Once all the errors are gone, you can revert the changes you made in the overrides to point to that ${package-name} again, and continue your development cycle normally (let Vaadin take care of the npm install at the startup).


Hope this helps.
